# Background image hover not working in Colorbox modal

Tags: css, hover, modal-dialog, background-image, colorbox

I'm trying to restyle this lightbox plugin (https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox), but the hover on my previous and next buttons isn't working with the other image I would like behind it. I've spent a good couple of hours on it, without much luck. Here is the code:

```
/* This is the image placed behind the previous and next buttons */
#cboxTopLeft{
width: 248px;
height: 91px;
background: url(images/projectnavbg.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
margin: 30px 20px -120px;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}

/* These are the buttons */
#cboxPrevious, #cboxNext {
border:0; 
padding:0; 
margin:0; 
overflow:visible; 
position:absolute;
text-indent:-9999px; 
z-index:1; 
width: 111px; 
height: 21px; 
bottom:375px;
}

#cboxPrevious:active, #cboxNext:active, #cboxSlideshow:active, #cboxClose:active {
outline:0;
}

#cboxPrevious{
left:30px; 
background: url(images/prevnextbtns.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

#cboxPrevious:hover{
background-position: 0px -25px;
}

#cboxNext{
left: 145px; 
background: url(images/prevnextbtns.png) 0 0 no-repeat; 
background-position: -115px 0px;
}

#cboxNext:hover{
left: 145px; 
background-position: -115px -25px;
}
```

Comment: Could you post your HTML as well?

Comment: The plugin uses background image from `images/controls.png`, if you want to restyle it, just change the image.